# SQL Lookup in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, lookup

I have an Access Database with a table [Inventory] with following fields:

```
[Inventory].[Warehouse]
[Inventory].[PartNumber]
```

I also have a query [TransactionsQry] with following fielfd:

```
[TransactionsQry].[PartNumber]
[TransactionsQry].[SumofTransactions]
```

Now I would like to make a new query which shows **all** part numbers per Warehouse (from table [Inventory]) and look up related (number of) transactions in query [TransactionsQry]. Not every part number in [Inventory] has transactions yet and if so I would like to display "0".

At first I successfully tried this with a DLookup, but the result is a very slow query for very little data.

That is why I tried the following (but unsuccessfully displaying only matched part numbers and an additional error message):

```
SELECT 
    Inventory.Warehouse AS Warehouse, 
    TransactionsQry.PartNumber AS PartNumber, 
    TransactionsQry.SumofTransactions AS SumofTransactions
FROM Inventory 
    INNER JOIN TransactionsQry ON Inventory.PartNumber = TransactionsQry.PartNumber;
```

Any help with solving this issue in SQL is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Add Parameter Value "SELECT" with a field to type something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be needing a LEFT JOIN based on what you need. Along with a Nz to treat Nulls as 0. Here is the corrected CODE

```
SELECT 
    Inventory.Warehouse AS Warehouse, 
    TransactionsQry.PartNumber AS PartNumber, 
    Nz(TransactionsQry.SumofTransactions, 0) AS SumofTransactions 
FROM 
    Inventory LEFT JOIN TransactionsQry 
ON 
    Inventory.PartNumber = TransactionsQry.PartNumber;
```

Comment: Paul, this piece of code works, thanks. But again I receive the dialog to input something on "SELECT". I read on this forum that the NZ function is not very efficient, would there be an alternative?

Comment: Input something on? I do not get it. Is it an error? Nz is the best function to use, the alternative is to use IIF with a check to Is Null, which is what Nz does for you. Could you point out to the article that says it is inefficient?

Comment: Hi Paul, in the mean time I discovered that I left an superfluous line of code at the top, now it works perfectly, thanks for your swift reply! The article about NZ versus IIF I read [here](http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html)

Comment: Glad you have it sorted, Please feel free to mark the answer that solved your trouble. Cheers for the link, will have a read through. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `left join` rather than `inner join` for this.  Also, table aliases make queries easier to read and write:

```
SELECT i.Warehouse AS Warehouse, 
       tq.PartNumber AS PartNumber, 
       nz(tq.SumofTransactions, 0) AS SumofTransactions
FROM Inventory as i LEFT JOIN
     TransactionsQry as tq
     ON i.PartNumber = tq.PartNumber;
```

However, I'm guessing that you really want a `group by`:

```
SELECT i.Warehouse AS Warehouse, 
       tq.PartNumber AS PartNumber, 
       nz(sum(tq.SumofTransactions), 0) AS SumofTransactions
FROM Inventory as i LEFT JOIN
     TransactionsQry as tq
     ON i.PartNumber = tq.PartNumber
GROUP BY i.Warehouse, tq.PartNumber;
```

Comment: This results in the following message: "Undefined function 'nvl' in expression" (I must say I am a rookie in Access and programming)

Comment: @Xavier . . . Oops.  That should have been `nz()` rather than `nvl()`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect like the code of @PaulFrancis does too. The only adjustment of your codes I made in my version is change `tq.PartNumber AS PartNumber` into `i.PartNumber AS PartNumber` (and the same in the "Group By"). If not, blank part numbers appeared in the list.